# A*pathing in swift implementation

Tags: ios, swift, path-finding

I have been following this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/4970/how-to-implement-a-pathfinding-with-cocos2d-tutorial to implement the A*pathing which is written in objective C.

My problem is that it never seems to be able to find a path to the ending Location and thus loops forever. I am also using JSTileMap.

My class

```
class ShortestPathStep: NSObject {
    var gScore: Int!
    var hScore: Int!
    var position: CGPoint!
    var parent: ShortestPathStep?

    init(loc: CGPoint) {
        super.init()
        gScore = 0
        hScore = 0
        position = loc

        parent = nil


    }
    func isEqualPath(other: ShortestPathStep) -> Bool {
        return CGPointEqualToPoint(self.position!,other.position!)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
   func fScore() -> Int {
        return self.gScore! + self.hScore!
    }
}
 func startPathfinding(startPoint:CGPoint, endPoint:CGPoint) { // take in values of CGPoint not tiled coordinate system
    var layer : TMXLayer = map.layerNamed("World1")
    var currentTile = layer.tileAt(hero.position)
    var initialPosition = layer.coordForPoint(currentTile.position)
    var endPosition = layer.coordForPoint(endPoint)
    var pathFound = false
    //self.openList = []
    //self.closedList = []
    insertInOpenSteps(ShortestPathStep(loc: initialPosition))
    do {
            println(openList.count)
            var currentStep = openList.objectAtIndex(0) as ShortestPathStep
          //println(currentStep)
            closedList.addObject(currentStep)
            openList.removeObjectAtIndex(0)
            println(currentStep.position)
            if CGPointEqualToPoint(currentStep.position, endPosition) {
                println("I found a path")
                // this part never runs
                pathFound = true
                openList = []
                closedList = []
                var tmpStep: ShortestPathStep! = currentStep
                do {
                    println(tmpStep.gScore)
                    println(tmpStep.hScore)
                } while tmpStep != nil
                break
            }
            var adjacentTiles = walkableAdjacentTiles(currentStep.position)
            for adjacentNodes in adjacentTiles {
                var step : ShortestPathStep! = ShortestPathStep(loc: adjacentNodes.CGPointValue())
                println(adjacentNodes.CGPointValue())
                if closedList.containsObject(adjacentNodes) {
                    step = nil
                    continue
                 }
               var moveCost = costToMoveFromStep(currentStep as ShortestPathStep, toAdjacentStep: step)
               var index = openList.indexOfObject(step)
               if index == NSNotFound {
                    step.parent = currentStep as ShortestPathStep
                    step.gScore = currentStep.gScore + moveCost
                    step.hScore = computeHScoreFromCoord(step.position, toCoord: endPosition)
                    insertInOpenSteps(step)
                    step = nil
                }

               else {
                    step = openList.objectAtIndex(index) as ShortestPathStep
                    if (currentStep.gScore + moveCost) < step.gScore {
                        step.gScore = currentStep.gScore + moveCost
                        insertInOpenSteps(step)
                        openList.removeObjectAtIndex(index)
                        step = nil
                    }
                }
            }

            println(openList.count)
        } while openList.count > 0

        if CGPointEqualToPoint(initialPosition, endPoint) {
           println("You are there already")
        }
}
func computeHScoreFromCoord(fromCoord:CGPoint,toCoord:CGPoint) -> Int {
        // Here we use the Manhattan method, which calculates the total number of step moved horizontally and vertically to reach the
        // final desired step from the current step, ignoring any obstacles that may be in the way
        return abs(Int(toCoord.x - fromCoord.x)) + abs(Int(toCoord.y - fromCoord.y))
    }

    func isValidTile(location:CGPoint) -> Bool {
        var node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
        if node.name == "collision" {
            return true
        }
        else {
            return true
        }
    }

    func walkableAdjacentTiles(tileLoc:CGPoint) -> NSMutableArray {
        var tmp : NSMutableArray = [] // 0 = not walkable 1 = walkable  (left,right,up,down)
        var layer : TMXLayer = map.layerNamed("World1")
        var position = layer.coordForPoint(hero.position)
        var right: Bool = isValidTile(CGPoint(x: position.x + 1, y: position.y))
        var left: Bool = isValidTile(CGPoint(x: position.x - 1, y: position.y))
        var up: Bool = isValidTile(CGPoint(x: position.x , y: position.y + 1))
        var down: Bool = isValidTile(CGPoint(x: position.x, y: position.y - 1))

        var p : CGPoint
        if left {
            var p = CGPointMake(position.x - 1, position.y)
            tmp.addObject(NSValue(CGPoint: p))

          //  layer.removeTileAtCoord(p)
        }
        if right {
            var p = CGPointMake(position.x + 1, position.y)
            tmp.addObject(NSValue(CGPoint: p))

         //   layer.removeTileAtCoord(p)
        }
        if up {
            var p = CGPointMake(position.x, position.y + 1)
            tmp.addObject(NSValue(CGPoint: p))

           // layer.removeTileAtCoord(p)
        }
        if down {
            var p = CGPointMake(position.x, position.y - 1)
             tmp.addObject(NSValue(CGPoint: p))

         //   layer.removeTileAtCoord(p)
        }
        return tmp

    }
    func insertInOpenSteps(step: ShortestPathStep) {
        var stepFScore = step.fScore()
        var count = openList.count
        var i = 0
        for i; i < count; i++ {
            if stepFScore <= self.openList.objectAtIndex(i).fScore() {
                break
            }
        }
        self.openList.insertObject(step, atIndex: i)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error with your code around here:

```
var tmpStep: ShortestPathStep! = currentStep
do {
    println(tmpStep.gScore)
    println(tmpStep.hScore)
} while tmpStep != nil
break
```

As you are not changing the value of tmpStep at any point then you are never going to be able to determine it is null. Also, you are force unwrapping tmpStep which will cause a runtime error if tmpStep does become nil.

After reading the ray wenderlich guide I recommend the following changes to your code:

```
var tmpStep: ShortestPathStep? = currentStep;
do {
    println(tmpStep?.gScore)
    println(tmpStep?.hScore)
    tmpStep = tmpStep?.parent // Changes the value of tmpStep to traverse the list. 
} while tmpStep != nil
```

This should fix your issue.

Hope it helps.

---

#### Update:

From your source code I can see a number of issues of why the path finding isn't working:

---

1: as mentioned before, you need to change to these lines:

```
var tmpStep: ShortestPathStep? = currentStep
do {
    println(tmpStep?.gScore)
    println(tmpStep?.hScore)
    tmpStep = tmpStep?.parent
} while tmpStep != nil
break
```

---

2: In your `walkableAdjacentTiles` function, you need to change this line:

```
var position = layer.coordForPoint(hero.position)
```

to

```
var position = tileLoc
```

In order to keep updating the adjacency list, otherwise the algorithm just purely looks at one single position and never completes the path.

---

3: At the beginning of your `startPathfinding` function, you need to make sure you're clearing the closed and open lists.

```
func startPathfinding(startPoint:CGPoint, endPoint:CGPoint) { // take in values of CGPoint not tiled coordinate system
    self.openList.removeAllObjects()
    self.closedList.removeAllObjects()
    // Rest of code here.
```

---

4: and finally, you're checking an incorrect contains on this line:

```
var step : ShortestPathStep! = ShortestPathStep(loc: adjacentNodes.CGPointValue())

    if closedList.containsObject(adjacentNodes) {
        step = nil
        continue
    }
```

This needs to be checking the step, not the adjacency list

```
for adjacentNodes in adjacentTiles {
    var step : ShortestPathStep! = ShortestPathStep(loc: adjacentNodes.CGPointValue())

    if closedList.containsObject(step) {
        step = nil
        continue
    }
```

---

This should make the necessary changes to make the algorithm work. Let me know if there are any more problems.

Comment: still having the same issues so far

Comment: What are the same issues so far? That the code block isn't executing or that you are still in an infinite loop?

Comment: If you can share with me your project I can take a look and point you in the correct direction.

Comment: It's the portion where I commented "this path never runs "and where I print" this path is found" which never executes .  It is still in an infinite loop yes

Comment: https://github.com/wraithseeker/TestGame?files=1 For the code files of the project it is at the github however I cant upload the Xcode project and I have to email it to you

Comment: Okay, I've found the problems in your code. I shall update my answer with the line changes.

Comment: Another thing I missed out earlier was that my endLocation was bugged but I went to fix it + amending code according to what u pointed out. The infinite loop stops now but it still isn't even able to find a path to the other location. I tried removing the tiles that are processed by the algorithmn for visual purposes and it seemed to crash the app somehow.

Comment: I ran some debugging and it seems that the currentStep retrieved at the start of the do While loop in the func startPathfinding prints out the same position all the time which seems to be the present issue so far

Comment: Actually I solved the problem, the problem was that I already had a point converted to tile coordinates but then I converted it again to tile coordinates which bugged out the whole thing

Comment: actually there is another problem now, it is unable to figure out a path to the exit if collisions are involved and it runs endlessly now. I updated the code here. It seems to do fine with movements involving left and right but not up and down for some weird reason.

http://pastebin.com/3atuNbG0

Comment: Wouldn't the code at: var tmpStep: ShortestPathStep? = currentStep still cause a problem in the following loop since the do is executed at least once and the tmpStep may indeed return nil? Better to wrap the entire thing in an if let statement and only execute the inner loop if the variable is not nil.

Comment: Almost. It is cleaner to do an `if let` as you've suggested. However the optional unwrapping in the `do {...} while` loop of `tmpStep` prevents any runtime errors.

Comment: Just noticed that the code before the update doesn't have these. I'll add them in (It would produce a compile time error anyway if this was implemented). Good spot.

Answer (score 0):

First, You have at least one potential infinite loop in your code

If tmpStep is nil, this piece of code loops forever:

```
do {
    println(tmpStep.gScore)
    println(tmpStep.hScore)
} while tmpStep != nil
```

Second, you should indent your code correctly in StackOverflow, it is really hard to find other bugs with the current incorrect indentation

Comment: I edited and indented the code  now. The condition above that block of code doesn't ever run yet.